# If condition on event listeners

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to  use the `addEventListener` as a condition
so that if the condition is true by the clicking of  the
image, the code executes, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
HTML
<div class = "content">
<img src = "dog.png" alt =  ""   id  = "firstImage" >
<img src = "coatOfArm.png" alt =  ""  id  = "second 
Image" >
<p  id = "score" >0</p>
</div>

JavaScript
var firstImage = 
document.getElementById("firstImage");
var secondImage = 
document.getElementById("secondImage");

var score= document.getElementById("score");
var totalScore_1 = 0;
var totalScore_2 = 0;

firstImage.addEventListeners("click",function() {
totalScore_1++;
score.innerHTML = totalScore_1;
}) 

secondImage.addEventListeners("click", function() { 
totalScore_2++;
score.innerHTML = totalScore_2;
}) 

function increScore() {

if(first Image clicked == true){

firstImage. append(score) ;
} else{
secondImage. append(score) ;
} 
} ;

increScore() ;
```

Comment: `first Image clicked == true` is invalid syntax

Comment: you can call `increScore` inside event listeners passing a param, which identifies whether to append score or not

Comment: I meant firstImage.clicked == true. Is it also invalid syntax?

Comment: Its `addEventListener` not `addEventListeners`. anyway you wont be able to get the object `clicked` property as your function will run before the `click` event. (not to mention there is no such property)